# iphone sqlite undefined symbol errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, xcode4.2, i386

I am trying to learn sqlite for the iphone and am using the tutorial at this link:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

I created a single view application and copied the code from the tutorial into the viewcontroller.h and .m files.  After each section in the tutorial I compiled the code to make sure it is still working.  I first get an error after I copy in the "Creating the Database and Table" section.  I get the following errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have searched countless forums and tried numerous things.  I have imported libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib.  I am using xcode 4.2.  It seems to be related to sqlite framework but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Do you import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"? It might not be at the same path but you probably need this header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add the libraries/frameworks for sqlite.  Use this reference and add the entries for sqlite.  Maybe you didn't add them to your current target?:

[add frameworks](http://codingcluster.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-43.html)

Comment: I feel quite dumb.  I had the libsqlite.dylib included in the Test Target not the main Target.  Thanks so much.